# Changing the value of alternated rows of a vector in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have the following NumPy array in python:

```
V = 2*np.ones([7,1]); V[0]=1; V[6]=1
```

Which will give me:

```
V = ([[1.],
      [2.],
      [2.],
      [2.],
      [2.],
      [2.],
      [1.],])
```

How can I change only the terms with odd indexes? For example, change the terms on the rows 1,3 and 5, to 4 (counting the first one as row 0) like the one below:

```
V = ([[1.],
      [4.],
      [2.],
      [4.],
      [2.],
      [4.],
      [1.],])
```

Is there a simpler way than to start a loop and check every element one by one? In this problem, I adopted a 7x1 column vector, but I want to solve for the general case of an Nx1 array. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use slicing operator like

```py
V[1::2] = 4
```

this mean start from the second entry, 1, and takes steps by 2 from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate()` on `V`:

```
for i,j in enumerate(V):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        V[i] = 4
```

Output:

```
array([[1.],
       [4.],
       [2.],
       [4.],
       [2.],
       [4.],
       [1.]])
```

Comment: Thank you! That was my first thought, but Simon's answer is what I've been looking for